# Unknown directive "init_by_lua_block" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I'm using an AWS EC2 `ubuntu 18.04` instance to set up a reverse proxy server to implement the concept of white labeling for a web app.

I installed `nginx` `openresty` and `lua`

Here are the respective versions:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
nginx version: openresty/1.15.8.2
Lua: 5.1.5
```

I'm facing problems creating the correct config file in `nginx`

Here is my `nginx.conf` file code:

```
user  ubuntu www;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    lua_shared_dict auto_ssl 1m;
    lua_shared_dict auto_ssl_settings 64k;
    resolver 8.8.8.8 ipv6=off;

    init_by_lua_block {
        auto_ssl = (require "resty.auto-ssl").new()
        auto_ssl:set("allow_domain", function(domain)
           return true
        end)
        auto_ssl:init()
    }

    init_worker_by_lua_block {
        auto_ssl:init_worker()
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate_by_lua_block {
            auto_ssl:ssl_certificate()
        }
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/resty-auto-ssl-fallback.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/resty-auto-ssl-fallback.key;

        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host app.mydomain.com;
            proxy_set_header Referer $host$uri;
            proxy_buffer_size          128k;
            proxy_buffers              4 256k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;

            proxy_set_header User-Agent $http_user_agent;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

            proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
            proxy_set_header Accept-Language $http_accept_language;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  https;
            proxy_read_timeout 5m;

            proxy_pass https://app.mydomain.com;
        } 
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            content_by_lua_block {
                auto_ssl:challenge_server()
            }
        }

        location / {
           return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:8999;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        client_max_body_size 128k;

        location / {
            content_by_lua_block {
                auto_ssl:hook_server()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I restart the `nginx` service, I'm getting the below error:

```
unknown directive "init_by_lua_block" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I learned that I had to start the server using `openresty` instead of `nginx`.

So I ran the below command and it worked:

```
sudo systemctl start openresty.service
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the same error. On ubuntu 18.04 it worked:

1. Install nginx lua module via apt (this will install `libnginx-mod-http-ndk` too):

```
sudo apt install libnginx-mod-http-lua
```

2. Add at the top of your `nginx.conf` file the directives to load the modules:

```
load_module modules/ndk_http_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_http_lua_module.so;
```

3. After you add the blocks of lua code (for example, as indicated in the official [Quick Start Guide](https://github.com/knyar/nginx-lua-prometheus#quick-start-guide)), make sure the path of the following line is correct:

```
lua_package_path "/path/to/nginx-lua-prometheus/?.lua;;";
```

The directory `nginx-lua-prometheus` is the one you have to clone form: https://github.com/knyar/nginx-lua-prometheus